# What does it mean to say let declarations are hoisted but not initialized?

Tags: javascript, var, let

I know that snippet below results in ReferenceError:

```
console.log(b);
let b = 3;
```

And i've read that it wouldn't fail if we were using `var` instead of `let`.
[MDN documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Variable_hoisting), claims that let declarations are hoisted too, but they are not **initialized**
What confuses me is that initialization, how can it even matter when we are talking about ReferenceError.

In the code below,

```
let b;
console.log(b);
b = 3;
```

initialization is written after the `console.log(b)` but this doesn't make any ReferenceError, so it doesn't make sense to say that in the first snippet exception is thrown because the variable is not initialized.

Could anyone please clarify these things please?

Comment: let declarations are NOT hoisted - oh, wait, they are (according to that link) ... but not in the same way ... they are in a temporal dead zone between the top of the scope block and where the declaration actually is ... to stop you from doing what you did in the first example :p

Comment: At the line where `let b;` is, it gets initialized. If there's no `=` to the right of it, `undefined` gets assigned to it - accessing `undefined` doesn't throw, Accessing a variable that hasn't been initialized yet is a completely different thing, and does throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `let` (and `const`) declaration will throw an error if accessed *before* **initialized**.

**What do that mean?**

You'll get an error if you try to access a variable before the program has reached the line with the declaration:

```js
try{
  console.log(b)
}catch(e){
  console.error(e) //ReferenceError
}

let b //b initalized here (b===undefined)

console.log(b) //undefined
b=3   //Reassign b with 3
console.log(b) //3
```

The initialization happens even if the `let` lacks `=value` part, in this case, with the value `undefined`, so it won't throw error anymore.

That's why you can't omit the `=value` part from a `const` declaration: it would be initalized with `undefined` and couldn't be reassigned later.

**Also note that** this kind of error is different from the error when trying to access an *undefined* variable: the former is thrown even if the variable is defined (in another scope):

```js
let b=1
console.log(b) //1
{
  //Different scope
  try{
    console.log(b)
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e) //ReferenceError: the inner b shadows the outer, but not yet initialized
  }
  let b=2
  console.log(b) //2
}
```